# Solution for saving array data in text file line by line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, save, text-files

```
[r1 c1]= size(cluster_head);
r1
fid=fopen('na.txt','w');
for f=1:r1
    f
    for m = 1:c1
        %value of cluster in chrosome
        a= cluster_head(1,m);
        temp = find(neighbors1(cluster_head(1,m),:));
        disp('neighbour')
        temp
        [r c]= size(temp);
        k(1,1)=cluster_head(1,m);
        for n=2:c+1
            if(temp(1,n-1)~=k(1,1))
                k(f,n)= temp(1,n-1);
                save solution.txt k(f,n) -ASCII
            end
        end
        fprintf('%d Iterations completed\n',m);
    end
end
```

Need `k(f,n)` to save in text file line by line. 
But solution.txt only store the last solution value in 1st row overwrite all others or previous solutions.

Comment: Welcome Hammad. Please try to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your posts, and also provide [mcve examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because every call to `save` overwrites the file contents with values of listed variables, which is `k(f,n)` in your code. So what remains in the file at last is the last element of `k` that satisfies the `if` criteria.

if you want to save all your data using `save`, you need to collect your data in a single variable and call `save` once. Take a look at following examples:

```matlab
%% save a row vector to file
row = 1:4;
save row.txt row -ascii
```

> 1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00

```matlab
%% 
col = (1:4)';
save col.txt col -ascii
```

> 1.0000000e+00
>   2.0000000e+00
>   3.0000000e+00
>   4.0000000e+00

```matlab
%% save a matrix to file
mat = reshape(1:4, [2, 2]);
save mat.txt mat -ascii
```

> 1.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00
>   2.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00

```matlab
%% save a matrix as column, with columns precedency
mat2 = mat(:);
save mat_colsfirst.txt mat2 -ascii
```

> 1.0000000e+00
>   2.0000000e+00
>   3.0000000e+00
>   4.0000000e+00

```matlab
%% save a matrix as column, with rows precedency
mat3 = mat';
mat3 = mat3(:);
save mat_rowsfirst.txt mat3 -ascii
```

> 1.0000000e+00
>   3.0000000e+00
>   2.0000000e+00
>   4.0000000e+00

Another option is to use `fprintf` which is a little more complicated, since you need to keep the file handle. But using `fprintf` you can append new lines to file. The other advantage is that you can control the formatting of outcome:

```matlab
filename = 'mat2.txt';
% open the file
% 'w': Open or create new file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any.
% 'n': Your system byte ordering (native)
% 'US-ASCII': ASCII character encoding
fileID = fopen(filename, 'w', 'n', 'US-ASCII');
mat = reshape(1:4, [2, 2]);
for jj=1:2
    for ii=1:2
        % write one of mat elements with 1 digit after floating point in a new line
        fprintf(fileID, '%.1f\n', mat(ii, jj));
    end
end
% close the file
fclose(fileID);
% display file contents in command window
type(filename)
```

> 1.0
>   2.0
>   3.0
>   4.0

Comment: Kindly give me a little more favour in temp variable i get  2 3 5   and i have fixed K(1,1) before loop . i want K(1,1) element to temp element store in a single row. Actually i am beginner in Matlab .

Comment: I'm sorry @HammadShafiq, I really don't follow. Try to describe the problem in a different way. Is it the temp variable or file contents that you have problem with?

Comment: Dear i have solved the problem finally. Thanks for your help.